# How to identify a set of dates from a string in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string, rubygems

I have the following strings

```
"sep 04 apr 06"
"29th may 1982"
"may 2006 may 2008"
"since oct 11"
```

Output

```
"September 2004 and April 2006"
"29 May 1982"
"May 2006 and May 2008"
"October 2011"
```

Is there a way to obtain the dates from these string. I used the gem 'dates_from_string', but it is unable to correctly obtain date from first scenario.

Comment: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Natural_Language_Date_Parsing
--> May be it will use for u

Comment: None of them are able to handle the first scenario, they identify only one date.

Comment: First scenario,its confusing.Do you want to have a range between two dates or separates date which belongs to Sep Month or Apr
you can use date parse rails console to have the bellow output but it will neglect the one month from the input
Date.parse("sep 04 apr 06")  => Tue, 04 Apr 2006

Comment: Where did these input strings came from? Could you change them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I took is as follows:

1. Divide the string into an array of words.
2. If the array contains fewer than two words, return an array containing all the date strings found; else go to step 3.
3. If the array contains at least three words and the first three words represent a date, save it, delete the first three words in the array and repeat step 2; else go to step 4.
4. If the first two words represent a date, save it, delete the first two words in the array and repeat step 2; else go to step 5.
5. Delete the first word in the array and go to step 2.

I search for dates using the class method [Date::strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime). `strptime` employs a format string. For example, `'%d %b %Y'` searches for the day of the month, followed by a space, followed by a (case-insensitive) three-character month abbreviation ('Jan', 'Feb',...,'Dec'), followed by a four-digit year. (I initially consider using [Date::parse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse), but that does not discriminate dates adequately.)

**Code**

I first generate all the `strptime` format strings of interest for month, day and year:

```
MON = %w{ %b %B } # '%b' for 'Jan', '%B' for 'January'
YR  = %w{ %y %Y } # '%y' for '11', '%Y' for 2011
DAY = %w{ %d }    # '4', '04' or '28' 

PERM3 = MON.product(YR, DAY).
            flat_map { |arr| arr.permutation(3).to_a }.
            map { |arr| arr.join(' ') }
  #=> ["%b %y %d", "%b %d %y", "%y %b %d", "%y %d %b", "%d %b %y", "%d %y %b",
  #    "%b %Y %d", "%b %d %Y", "%Y %b %d", "%Y %d %b", "%d %b %Y", "%d %Y %b",
  #    "%B %y %d", "%B %d %y", "%y %B %d", "%y %d %B", "%d %B %y", "%d %y %B",
  #    "%B %Y %d", "%B %d %Y", "%Y %B %d", "%Y %d %B", "%d %B %Y", "%d %Y %B"]
```

I then do the same for permutations of day and month and month and year:

```
PERM2 = MON.product(YR).
            concat(MON.product(DAY)).
            flat_map { |arr| arr.permutation(2).to_a }.
            map { |arr| arr.join(' ') }               
  #=> ["%b %y", "%y %b", "%b %Y", "%Y %b", "%B %y", "%y %B",
  #    "%B %Y", "%Y %B", "%b %d", "%d %b", "%B %d", "%d %B"]
```

I then proceed as follows:

```
require 'date'

def pull_dates(str)
  arr = str.split
  dates = []
  while arr.size > 1
    if arr.size > 2
      a = depunc(arr[0,3])
      if date?(a, PERM3)
        dates << a.join(' ')
        arr.shift(3)
        next
      end
    end
    a = depunc(arr[0,2])
    if date?(a, PERM2)
      dates << a.join(' ')
      arr.shift(2)
      next
    end
    arr.shift
  end
  dates
end
```

`depunc` removes any punctuations at the beginning and end of the string `arr.join(' ')`.

```
def depunc(arr)
  arr.join(' ').gsub(/^\W|\W$/,'').split  
end
```

`date?` determines if the three- or two-element string `arr` represents a date. I first obtain a "cleaned" string from `arr`, and then search through the applicable `strptime` format strings (the argument `perm`), looking for one that shows the cleaned string can be converted to a date.

```
def date?(arr, perm)
  clean = to_str_and_clean(arr)
  perm.find do |s|
    begin
      d = Date.strptime(clean, s)
      return true
    rescue
      false 
    end
  end
  false
end
```

`to_str_and_clean` returns a cleaned string that has punctuation removed and strings such as `'st'`, `'nd'`, `'rd'`, and `'th'` following the numerical representation of the day.

```
def to_str_and_clean(arr)
  str = arr.map { |s| s[0][/\d/] ? s.to_i.to_s : s }.join(' ').tr('.?!,:;', '')
end
```

**Example**

Let's try it.

```
str =
"Bubba sighted a flying saucer on sep 04 2013 and again in apr 06. \
Greta was born on 29th may 1982. Hey, may 2006 may 2008 are two years apart.\
We have been at loose ends since oct 11 of this year."

pull_dates(str)
  #=> ["sep 04 2013", "apr 06", "29th may 1982", "may 2006 may", "oct 11"]
```

Well, as you see, it's not perfect. Some tweaking is required, but this might get you started.

Answer (score 2):

When you say "unfortunately I can't predict in which format the date is going to be in.", you imply that you actually need "natural language parsing". Which is something core Date or DateTime objects cannot and should not do.

So, either you will need to parse the strings so you can present them to the more strict parser in an understandable format. Like `DateTime.parse('sep 04')`. For your examples, it could be as simple as:

```
datestring = 'sep 04 apr 06'
matches = datestring.match(/[a-z]{3}\s\d{2,4}/)
if matches.many?
  matches.map{|m| Date.parse(m) }.join(' and ')
else
  Date.parse(datestring)
end
```

However, when you want true natural language parsing, have a look at [Chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic). Which has all sorts of fancy parsers like `Chronic.parse('summer')`.

Edit: on closer inspection, it seems Chronic too can only identify one string, so your example `'sep 04 apr 06'` still needs some pre-processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DateTime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-_strptime) class like so:

```
DateTime.parse('sep 04 apr 06')
```

which outputs a DateTime object:

```
#<DateTime: 2006-04-04T00:00:00+00:00 ((2453830j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: but this will not work for 'DateTime.parse("may 2006 may 2008")', will throw invalid date error:

Comment: But those are two seperate dates. September 2004 and April 2006.

Comment: Indeed, you'll need to separate those two dates if you want it to work.

Comment: You'd have to use regex to split those strings containing two or more dates. As for parsing usually known dates, my answer has some added value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateTime.strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) method

Comment: strptime requires format as an argument and unfortunately I can't predict in which format the date is going to be in.